# Deleting data (rows) after encounter a negative value

Tags: vba, excel, rows

I have the following problem:

In the worksheet, there is a series of data of a tensile test.

Up to to 3k (give or take) points only positive date values exists (data I need to plot,and do statistical analysis). Afterwards appears some negative points and them again some positive values with can be considered noise. e.g,

```
 Line         A B C D
  1k          1 2 3 4
  2k          5 6 7 8 
  3k          9 1 2 3
  4k          1 2 3 -3
  5k          1 1 1 1
```

I would like to delete/clear the rows after the first negative value. (in this case from line 4k until the last row).

I have a bit of code to identify the line were the first negative value appears.

```
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim aux_linha As Integer
Dim i As Integer

flag = False
i = 3
While i < 20000 And flag = False

' 5 is the column index from which to remove the noisy data

    If Cells(i, 5) < 0 Then 

        flag = True
        aux_linha = i
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend

Cells(4, 10) = aux_linha 'store the value
```

I tried to do a for cycle to delete the rows but it takes forever

```
For i = 1 To 10000 'excessive number of lines
    Rows(aux_linha).Row.Delete

Next
```

Can anyone help to solve this problem?!

Answer (score 0):

Create a range, then delete the whole thing:

```
Range(aux_linha & ":" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Delete
```

Note: you can also drastically simplify your loop by skipping the exit flag test and manual incrementing by just using a For loop and exiting it when you hit your value:

```
For i = 3 To 20000
    If Cells(i, 5) < 0 Then 
        aux_linha = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```